# Check if value exists in object

Tags: javascript

I have object:

```
var roles = { roles: [0: { name: 'admin' }, 1: { name: 'user' }] }
```

How I can check if value `user` exists?

I tried do:

```
console.log(('user' in roles));
```

But this return `false`. Why?

Comment: Your object is not valid since it has `roles: 0: {name....`. Can you provide a correct object?

Comment: I think you need to edit again. the `[` you added does not fix this. Replace it with a `{`

Comment: do you have an array in roles or an object with keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a proper object, you could treat `roles.roles` as array and find the value with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

This works for any array like structure with an assignment to an array with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
function check(name) {
    return Object.assign([], roles.roles).some(o => o.name === name);
}

var roles = { roles: { 0: { name: 'admin' }, 1: { name: 'user' } } };

console.log(check('user'));
console.log(check('bar'));
```

By taking an array directly, you coult omit the assignment part.

```js
function check(name) {
    return roles.roles.some(o => o.name === name);
}

var roles = { roles: [{ name: 'admin' }, { name: 'user' }] };

console.log(check('user'));
console.log(check('bar'));
```

Answer (score 2):

[**in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator checks for property not for it's values

```js
let test = {'a':1,'b':2}

console.log('a' in test)
console.log(1 in test)
```

**How can i search values**

Here using [**`some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method of array i am checking whether desired value is in object or not.

```js
var roles = { roles: [{ name: 'admin' },{ name: 'user' }] }

let searchValue = (input,searchKey) => {
  return input.some(( {name} ) => name === searchKey)  //
}

console.log(searchValue(roles.roles, 'user'))
console.log(searchValue(roles.roles, 'user not foound'))
```

Comment: How I can search values?